# UITableViewCell with stretchable background image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have cells in `UITableView`, I have made custom frame for the label on cell and this frame is resize according to the text.

But my problem is that how I can show those texts inside the bubble (image) as the text size increase the bubble image size also increases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code for image you use :

```
- (UIImage *)stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:(NSInteger)leftCapWidth topCapHeight:(NSInteger)topCapHeight
```

Comment: Check this link http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-custom-chat-view-and-emoticons/

Comment: ;exactly what i want is give in this link.but facing bit problem to implement it

Comment: What kind of Problem?Try editing you code steps wise,according to tutorial,it will work out.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

In Custom Cell.m file :

```
bgImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30, 80, 40)];
[self.contentView addSubview:bgImageView];

messageContentView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
messageContentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
messageContentView.editable = NO;
messageContentView.scrollEnabled = NO;
[messageContentView sizeToFit];
[self.contentView addSubview:messageContentView];
```

And in `tableView:cellForRowAtindexPath` method:

```
static CGFloat padding = 20.0;  
CGSize textSize = {260.0 , 10000.0};
CGSize size = [message sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13] constrainedToSize:textSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
size.width += (padding/2);
UIImage *bgImage = nil;

    if([sender isEqualToString:@"you"])
    {
        bgImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"orange.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:24 topCapHeight:15];

     [cell.messageContentView setFrame: CGRectMake(padding, padding*2, size.width, size.height)];

        [cell.bgImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.messageContentView.frame.origin.x - padding/2,cell.messageContentView.frame.origin.y - padding/2,size.width+padding, size.height+padding)];
    }
    else
    {
        bgImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"aqua.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:24  topCapHeight:15];
                [cell.messageContentView setFrame:CGRectMake(320 - size.width - padding,padding*2,size.width, size.height)];
                [cell.bgImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.messageContentView.frame.origin.x - padding/2,  cell.messageContentView.frame.origin.y - padding/2,size.width+padding,size.height+padding)];

    }

    cell.bgImageView.image = bgImage;
```

Answer (score 2):

you can stretch the image with caps, depending on your image shape it could work

You can use this code

```
//Your image view
UIImageView *imageView;
//Your image
UIImage *image;

//Left cap is the space you dont wanna stretch on the left side and right side of the image
int leftCap = 20;
//Left cap is the space you dont wanna stretch on the top side and bottom side of the image
int topCap = 20;
//this will only stretch the inner side of the image
imageView.image = [image stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:leftCap topCapHeight:topCap];
```

for more information check this [tutorial](http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/08/stretchable-images-and-buttons/)

Comment: I just wanted that my text which are dynamic in size will appear  in bubble image in UITableview cell

Comment: @AlokSrivastava what do you mean whit bubble image?

Comment: I think he means something like SMS app

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafith:bubble image means simply a background image of UItablevie cell which should be stretchable as the cell size is increased